# Asp.Net Form submit using URL parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

That's my URL:

```html
http://localhost:7071/TODO?page=1&codcat=56
```

It returns me a simple form , it is my form of research:

```html
       <div class="col-md-8">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TODO", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <p>
                    Find in ...: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </p>
            }
            <br />
        </div>
```

The Search method in TODO control is :

```html
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int? codcat)
        {

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "title_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var todos = from v in db.TODOs 
                         join cv in db.TODO_CATEGORIA on v.ID equals cv.ID_TODO
                         where cv.ID_CATEGORIA == codcat select v;
            
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                todos = todos.Where(s => s.TODO_TITLE.Contains(searchString)
                                    || s.DESCRIPTION.Contains(searchString) 
                    );
            }


            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "title_desc":
                    todos = todos.OrderByDescending(s => s.TODO_TITLE);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    todos = todos.OrderBy(s => s.DATE);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    todos = todos.OrderByDescending(s => s.DATE);
                    break;
                default:
                    todos = todos.OrderBy(s => s.TODO_TITLE);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 21;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(todos.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)); 

        }
```

The problem is that the codcat parameter is sent by the form as null.

How could I do to the form keeping the value of the parameter codcat and send the parameter research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The one way** is to use hidden fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="codcat" value="@Request.QueryString["codcat"]" />
```

When submitting a form the POST request is sent to the server, and all your GET request's parameters are left behind.

**OR** to use this:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, FormMethod method);
```

**OR** this overload of BeginForm:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes);
```